# NestedScrollView inside CardView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In my cardview layout I've placed one Constraint Layout in which's NestedScrollView that isn't scrolling.
I've searched Stack Overflow, nothing works. This cardView layout is later placed in RecyclerView, if that matters. Below I launch also blueprint of layout. Only part of it is shown in recycler view, where user click's Floating Action Button view is expanding.  Where's problem?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/entire_card_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_cardview">

            <!--This is a ConstraintLayout for the fixed portion
                of the CardView. The elements
                that lie within the fixed portion of the CardView
                can be constrained to this layout.-->

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/fixed_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/teal_700"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab_expand"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_expand_more_24" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/hidden_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fixed_container"
                tools:visibility="visible">

                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_long" />


                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Blueprint of layout:
[image]

Comment: why do you have lots of constraint layouts?can you share your view design?

Comment: @Priyanka Sure, I've updated my post.

Comment: your code is working fine, i tested now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: app]your code is working fine. modified a little bit. please check it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/main_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/entire_card_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_cardview">

        <!--This is a ConstraintLayout for the fixed portion
            of the CardView. The elements
            that lie within the fixed portion of the CardView
            can be constrained to this layout.-->

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixed_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_expand"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.954"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/hidden_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fixed_container"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">
                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_long"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>


            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```